# Set each number from input to its own variable

Tags: python

How can I set each number from input to its own variable?

code:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:

    print(line)
```

input:

```
(25,6) (25,10)
```

I want

```
x1=25 
y1=6
x2= 25 
y2 =10
```

Comment: if it is coming from `stdin`  then it is a string.  Just asign it to one variable. and then parse it.

Comment: Using separate variables to hold related items instead of putting them in a compound type is an antipattern -- it suggests (strongly) that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: For example, a better structure for this would be `points=[ (25,6), (25,10) ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to extract the numbers from the input.

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    match = re.search(r'\((\d+),(\d+)\)\s*\((\d+),(\d+)\)', line)
    if match:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, match.groups())
```

Comment: I have to use sys.stdin, It is a test program for a different project

Comment: @help_me_program Doubtful that you "have to". Both do the same thing.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use `sys.stdin`, but how you process the line is the same.